# How to check if a vector is a part other vector in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors `x<-c("A","B")` and `y<-c("A", "B", "C")` I want to find if whole of x is contained in y. Also, **the order does not matter**, both elements in x should be a part of y.

Thanks!

Comment: OK. Hadd E. Nuff. You changed your name. But who am I to complain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check with:

```
sum(!x %in% y)==0
```

EDIT:

Or as suggested, you can achieve something more readable with

```
all(x %in% y)
```

Comment: why are you doing sum, it seems weird. Let me try.

Comment: Good point, I wasn't aware of `all`. I will edit

Comment: `sum(!x %in% y)==0` and `all(!x %in% y)==0` works perfectly given the above condition. Let me check it in my real program. :D

Comment: With `all` you just need to write `all(x %in% y)`.

Comment: Perfect guys!! :D Thanks a lot! My algorithm is on rage now. :P